# Connect to RabbitMQ takes too long time

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a `CentOS 6` machine and on it I installed `RabbitMQ 3.7.8`.

Then I write some sample to send and receive two messages.

All things are ok, but connection time. Connect from `PHP` with `AMQP` to `RabbitMQ` takes more than 5 Seconds.

My sample:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$a = microtime(true);
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('127.0.0.1', 5672, 'guest', 'guest', 
'/', false, 'AMQPLAIN', null, 'en_US', 30.0, 20.0, null);
$b = microtime(true);
$channel = $connection->channel();
$c = microtime(true);
$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
$d = microtime(true);
$msg = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
$e = microtime(true);

$msg = new AMQPMessage('Testtt Message!');
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
$f = microtime(true);
echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";

echo '<br/>Connection Time: ' . ($b - $a) . ' Sec.';
echo '<br/>Channel Time: ' . ($c - $b) . ' Sec.';
echo '<br/>Queue Time: ' . ($d - $c) . ' Sec.';
echo '<br/>Publish 1 Time: ' . ($e - $d) . ' Sec.';
echo '<br/>Publish 2 Time: ' . ($f - $e) . ' Sec.';
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

And result:

```
[x] Sent 'Hello World!' 
Connection Time: 5.1319510936737 Sec.
Channel Time: 0.0030379295349121 Sec.
Queue Time: 0.00053691864013672 Sec.
Publish 1 Time: 0.00059103965759277 Sec.
Publish 2 Time: 0.00010395050048828 Sec.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps this will help with your issue? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/jbNJG9OevtY
It is not a proper fix, but sounds like you have the same issue due to SELinux?

Comment: I check that and find SELinux status has been disabled before.

Comment: Rabbitmq is supposed to be used in CLI most of the times, so this would not matter. Not sure if you can do anything with this, a lot of things happen when a client connects from RabbitMq's POV.  You can try running the script with `strace` to narrow the problem. Maybe you have some [dns resolution issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/X0fJIf9O8A0)? Such connections are costly, should not be run in a web context anyway.

Comment: I am running and testing all of them in local host and no dns need there.